# Topology libraries

Tags: general-topology, math-software

I have been searching around for a library in some programming language (Java/C++/Haskell/python,etc) that can define topological entities and manipulate them. The only references I've found are to niche numerical packages that are highly specialized. For example, one link on this site http://www.math.uic.edu/t3m/ describes a package that can 'compute mod 2 Heegaard Floer Knot homology' - I'm looking for something a bit more general, say if you want to do some basic manipulation of topological spaces.

I'd be interested in a package that lets you do something like this (for example):

Let $\Omega$ be a VS over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$.

Let $\Lambda$ be a VS over $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension $2n$.

print Homeomorphic($\Omega$,$\Lambda$)

Wherein the results of the function above would tell you whether or not the two topological spaces you have just defined are homeomorphic. Does this type of software exist out there, or could it be in principle created?

Comment: I expect (hope) that people with some hands-on experience will suggest [interactive proof assistants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant) such as Coq and Mizar. These have by now considerable libraries of definitions and theorems, and though the learning curve seems initially steep, they may well have what you're looking for. I've seen various libraries for more specific areas of topology where there are known, tedious algorithms, e.g. computing homology of simplexes, knot groups, etc., but I don't know any that are open source, and often the software is just described in a paper.